# Howto: create file with current date and time on linux

Tags: linux, gzip

I have a cron job for creating a gzip file:

```
mysqldump... | gzip -c > myfile..sql.gz
```

I want `myfile` to be of the format "time_date.sql.gz"

How do I create file with the current date and time?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myfile_`date '+%F_%T'`.sql.gz
```